# Aprilaire 56 Humidistat not getting power

Tags: electrical, wiring, furnace, humidifier

I have an Aprialaire 56 humidistat that is connected to an Aprialaire 560 humidifier. Currently the humidifier is not turning on and after testing the wiring with a multimeter, the wires going in to the humidistat are not getting a current.

This system was installed by the previous homeowner and was tested and working previously to my knowledge.

The humidistat is wired into the furnace control panel in the `C` and `W2` terminals. From my research, `W2` is "stage 2" of the furnace heating cycle. My thought is to move the wire from `W2` to `W1` in order to draw power to the humidistat.

Are there any other remedies to troubleshoot why the humidistat and in return the humidifier are not powering on?

[image: wiring]

[image: humidistat wiring]

Comment: I would say that you are on the right track.  Perhaps  they thought previously that the only time they wanted additional humidification is whenever the house temperature dropped significantly below the set point of the t-stat.  These are the conditions when second stage in your system will be activated, not necessarily a bad strategy.  If you want more humidity, I see no reason not to switch one of those from stage 2 to stage 1.

Comment: Did you test with furnace running?  Not AC, not blower only, but burner on heat producing.

Comment: @PaulLogan thanks for the info, that makes a lot of sense. I didn't think I could mess anything up by switching it, I just wanted to double check. We got an Ecobee thermostat when we moved in, so that might be effecting when it hits stage 2 as well. I'll try switching to `W1`.

Comment: @Tyson yes, I made sure to test when the furnace was fully running (blower + heat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wired in this way, this should have never worked.  `W2` is the terminal that the thermostat uses to activate second stage heat. It is not energized by the furnace, but by the thermostat.

Also, it looks like the humidistat is not wired properly.  The wires from the furnace should be in the `R`, and `C` terminals. It looks like they're in the `I-`, and `R` instead.

> [image: Aprilaire 56 humidistat Wiring diagram]
>   <sup>*Figure H from manufacturer's installation instructions.*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the info about the wiring. Would you agree that `W1` is the correct place for the wire, as opposed to `W2`? I ask this because I tried tonight to switch it over to `W1` and then my Ecobee3 could not call up the heat any longer. I ended up having to use my old thermostat to get heat to work again (the blower had been working all along). So i'm wondering if have the humidistat going onto `W1` as well as the heat caused some "confusion" among the accessories. The Ecobee thought the heat was turned on, even though it was not.

Comment: Typically, yes.  Using W1 makes sense, however, without inspecting the wiring it might not be correct.  A better option might be to use the HUM terminals on the control board.  Though this will require an additional transformer, since HUM is at 120V.

Comment: @jamez14 did you fix the wiring at the humidistat? Moving the red wire from `I-` to `C`.  Then putting the white wire to `W1` at the thermostat should work.

Comment: yes, i moved the red from `I-` to `C`. I'll give it another try now to see if the old thermostat will play nice with the humidistat

Comment: With the old thermostat installed and moving the humidistat to `W1` i was able to get the humidifier working. Thank you so much! Now I just need to test out my Ecobee3 again and see if I can get it to work with the humidistat now connected to `W1`.

Comment: Ecobee still not working after I reinstalled it. I posted a new question though to hopefully solve this https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/128180/ecobee3-not-turning-on-heat-but-fan-is-on